# How to rebind space to enter in fish shell when in normal mode (vi bindings)

Tags: fish

I want to be able to run the current command (as I would by hitting enter) bu hitting space while in normal mode, and while running the vi keybindings, in the fish shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
bind --mode default ' ' execute
```

You can add that to the `fish_user_key_bindings` function, or in config.fish.